# DecimalFormat negative pattern oddity?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I can't find the answer in teh Googles or SO, and it's annoying me.

Reading [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), I find " If there is an explicit negative subpattern, it serves only to specify the negative prefix and suffix; the number of digits, minimal digits, and other characteristics are all the same as the positive pattern. That means that "#,##0.0#;(#)" produces precisely the same behavior as "#,##0.0#;(#,##0.0#)"." However, this code does not seem to follow with that:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class NumberFormatTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###;(#,###)");
        System.out.println(df.format(-1234.0));

        df.applyPattern("#,###;(#)");
        System.out.println(df.format(-1234.0));
    }
}
```

give an output of

```
(1,234)
(1,234
```

(note the missing paren in line 2)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug in DecimalFormat. See bug report http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6609740

Answer (score -2):

Try something

```
    DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
    System.out.println(df.format(-12999.0));// the output is: -12 999,0
```

This is working

Comment: It is indeed but it doesn't answer the question.